# U2 Toolkit for .NET - Entity Framework Sample "EntityFramework_CodeFirst2" not connecting

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4.1, u2, universe, u2netdk

I get this error when trying to modify the EntityFramework_CodeFirst and EntityFramework_CodeFirst2 projects:

> Opening Connection
> [U2][UCINET-UO] [U2][UCINET-UO]WIN32 API Error:10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine[Rocket U2][UCINET - UNIRPC][ErrorCode=81009] The RPC failed Error in Socket Send and dataLength:36
>
> Inner Exception:Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. Inner Exception:WIN32 API Error:10053An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine[Rocket U2][UCINET - UNIRPC][ErrorCode=81009] The RPC failed
> Error in Socket Send and dataLength:36

I have set my connection string to:

```
<add name="CustomerContext" connectionString="Database=dbPath;UserID=userId;Password=password;Server=serverIp;Pooling=false;ServerType=universe;ConnectTimeout=500;PersistSecurityInfo=true" providerName="U2.Data.Client" />
```

Using those same credentials I can successfully connect using the U2 DB Provider for .NET test connection program on both the ADO.NET and UniObjects connections. I just cannot get it to work for the EntityFramework_CodeFirst projects.

The UNIRPC is running on the host machine. Port 31438 is listening. Firewalls are off.

**EDIT:**
I have set the environment variables UCINETTRACE and UCINETTRACESWITCH and have a trace log of the DataAdapter Sample. This is a snippet of the interesting part. [Full trace here](http://pastebin.com/1kAXg3s4)

> 5/30/2012 10:56:53 AM:ThreadID: ThreadID: 11 Thread Name : Cursor #1--UciStatement::OpenServerCursor()  and SQL String::call *HS.OLEDBINFO('ACCTS', '', '', '', '', '1', '', 0, 1)
> 5/30/2012 10:56:53 AM:ThreadID: Exiting:ThreadID: 11 Thread Name : UciStatement::OpenServerCursor()
> 5/30/2012 10:56:53 AM:ThreadID: Entering:ThreadID: 11 Thread Name : UciStatement::AssociateServerCursor()
> 5/30/2012 10:56:53 AM:ThreadID: Exiting:ThreadID: 11 Thread Name : UciStatement::AssociateServerCursor()
> 5/30/2012 10:56:53 AM:ThreadID: Entering:ThreadID: 11 Thread Name : UciStatement::()ServerExecute
> 5/30/2012 10:56:53 AM:ThreadID: Entering:ThreadID: 11 Thread Name : UciStatement::ServerExecuteSql()
> 5/30/2012 10:56:53 AM:ThreadID: ThreadID: 11 Thread Name :  [U2][UCINET][UNIVERSE]:ERROR: CAN'T EXECDIRECT SELECT FROM @TMP

**EDIT 2:**
I have the HS.SALES example working and I am on UniVerse 11.4 (current). I spoke with Rocket Support and I did not know that I needed to authorize individual UV accounts with HS.ADMIN, which was likely the problem. I thought a solid connection to the database was going to cut it, especially since HS.SALES was working. I still need to "SQLize" my DICT files to allow them to work on ADO.NET (& EF) but I almost have it now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try DataAdapter Sample with same connection string? Is this working?
Could you please provide TRACE LOG? You need to set the following :

Trace and Debug
To debug your U2 Database Provider for .NET applications, you can use the U2 trace facility. To activate the trace facility, set the following environment variables:

SET UCINETTRACE=c:\temp

SET UCINETTRACESWITCH=4

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not familiar with setting up environment variables that way in Visual Studio (I'm using 2010 SP1). I searched online and found [this way of doing it](http://www.delphi-ts.com/blogs/lozzi/post/2007/04/06/Enable-Trace-Logging-with-UniObjectsNet.aspx). I'm not sure if that is correct, but when I run it, I get "_The type initializer for 'U2.Data.Client.Common.UniTrace' threw an exception_" and in the log file: "_ImageFileMachine:ImageFileMachine.I386I386
U2.Data.Client, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9ab9148678f4f448 Assembly is platform independent._"

Comment: You need to open Control Panel->System->Advanced System Settings->EnvironmentVarables->System varables. But you have first shutdown Visual Studio 2010. When you run the code, a log file will be generated . For example : c:\temp\ucinet*****.txt. Read http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2010/05/how-to-addedit-environment-variables-in-windows-7/

Comment: One more question. Did you try DataAdapter Sample Code?

Comment: Yes, I have switched to trying to the DataAdapter instead for now just  to get the connection working. DataAdapter Sample code is failing too.

Comment: Thank you for providing me log/trace file. I am working on it. I will update you soon.

Comment: It looks like subroutine [*HS.OLEDBINFO('ACCTS', '', '', '', '', '1', '', 0, 1)] is failing.
I would like to know the following:
1. What is your UniVerse Database Version?
2. Could you please send me server side log file? For example: C:\U2\UV\HS.SALES\ .hs_debuginfo
3. Go to your account and find the file ‘.hs_debuginfo’. See the line “STMT  SELECT….”
Did you try the sample as it is with HS.SALES account?

Comment: Thank you for your help, Rajan! I am closer to getting my db connected with Entity Framework now. I wish I could upvote your answer here b/c of all your help. When I get more reputation I will... Anyways, I will update my DICTs and if I have any further issues with Entity Framework I will edit my post.

Comment: You do not need to 'SQLize' the account. You can select multi-value field using UNNEST and U2ConnectionStringBuilder/FirstNormalForm=false. I do not understand what the problem with your account is. If you can send U2 Support strip version of your account, we can try something. Can you please send '.hs_debuginfo' to U2 Support? It will give us some idea.

Comment: U2 Support could not direct me to hs_debuginfo. I gave them the same client trace file as you. They gave me an updated version of the .dll (1.1.0.525) and new sample code, but I ran into the same error.

Comment: Please work with U2 Support in this issue. I have seen some reply in rocket customer portel.

Answer (score 0):

Caould please try U2NETDK v1.2.0? I hope it will solve the above mentioned problem.

U2NETDK v1.2.0 BETA contains U2 Database Add-ins for Visual Studio 2010. Now you can use VS2010 Server Explorer to populate U2 Tables, Views and Subroutines.

It will allow you to create DataSet and Entity Data Model.